# How to "rotate" an ellipse?

Tags: lua, ellipse, love2d

Using this:

```
local W, H = 100, 50

function love.draw()
  love.graphics.translate(love.graphics.getWidth()/2,love.graphics.getHeight()/2)
  for i = 1, 360 do
    local I = math.rad(i)
    local x,y = math.cos(I)*W, math.sin(I)*H
    love.graphics.line(0, 0, x, y)
  end
end
```

I can connect a line with the center of an ellipse (with length `W` and height `H`) and the edge. How do you 'rotate' the ellipse around it's center, with a parameter `R`? I know you can sort of do it with `love.graphics.ellipse` and `love.graphics.rotate` but is there any way I can get the coordinates of the points on a rotated ellipse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a Trigonometry problem, here is how the basic 2D rotation work. Imagine a point located at (x,y). If you want to rotate that point around the origin(in your case 0,0) by the angle θ, the coordinates of the new point would be located at (x1,y1) by using the following transformation

> x1 = x*cosθ − y*sinθ 
>   y1 = y*cosθ + x*sinθ

In your example, I added a new ellipse after rotations

```
function love.draw()
    love.graphics.translate(love.graphics.getWidth()/2,love.graphics.getHeight()/2)
    for i = 1, 360, 5 do
        local I = math.rad(i)
        local x,y = math.cos(I)*W, math.sin(I)*H
        love.graphics.setColor(0xff, 0, 0) -- red
        love.graphics.line(0, 0, x, y)
    end

  -- rotate by angle r = 90 degree
    local r = math.rad(90)
    for i = 1, 360, 5 do
        local I  = math.rad(i)
        -- original coordinates
        local x  = math.cos(I) * W 
        local y  = math.sin(I) * H
        -- transform coordinates
        local x1 = x * math.cos(r) - y * math.sin(r) 
        local y1 = y * math.cos(r) + x * math.sin(r) 
        love.graphics.setColor(0, 0, 0xff) -- blue
        love.graphics.line(0, 0, x1, y1)
    end
end
```

[image]